The longest sequence of consecutive integers all divisible by at least one prime from $\{2, \ldots, P_n\}$?
Working on prime numbers, it seems to me that for a given Prime noted $P_n$ :
The longest sequence of consecutive integers that are all divisible by at least one prime from $\{2, \ldots, P_n\}$ has length $< 2 P_n$.
What do you think? Is this true, or can you think of a counter-example? Can we prove it or deny it mathematically?
I have computed it up to $31$, but I don't have specific math software to compute it for larger numbers if anyone can?
Thank you

Note:  the question in the header doesn't match the one in the body.  The one in the header is the opposite of what you intend...you meant "not relatively prime to...".  The answer to the question as stated in the header is just $1$, since in any two consecutive natural numbers, one of them is even.  My posted solution below refers to the question in the body.

Note:  I see that a variant of this question was asked before, here.  They commenters found the same OEIS page I refer to.  As the prior question never got an answer, I'll leave my posted solution up.

Please see lulu's comment and amend the question title accordingly.

This is false.  According to A058989, the longest string of consecutive natural numbers each divisible by at least one of the first $14$ primes is $89$, but $p_{14}=43$.  After that point, the bound becomes much worse.
The sequence in question (that is, the first such sequence to occur), for $p_{14}=43$, starts at $14478292443584$ and can be verified here.
Note that I provided $90$ terms, the last one being out of the sequence just to confirm that the sequence wasn't even longer than $89$.

Thank you for you answer. But this actually confirmes the fact I suggest. Because what I said as you can read above is that the longest sequence is necesseraly inferior than 2*Pn. No?

I don't understand.  $89$ is $>2\times p_{14}$ which is $86$.

oh ok sorry. Ok that answers my question thank you very much
